# Measurement of a bipartite observable and choice of basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements

Consider two parties Alice and Bob that share a maximally entangled state

$$|\psi^-\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle-|10\rangle) $$

where $|0\rangle,|1\rangle$ are eigenstates of $\sigma_z$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Clearly

$$\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z|\psi^-\rangle=-|\psi^-\rangle $$

this means that Alice and Bob can measure the observable $\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z$ without destroying the whole state. But what does this mean locally? Does this mean that Alice can measure $\sigma_z$ locally on her system and same for Bob? Because in this case, calling $\psi=|\psi^-\rangle\langle\psi^-|$, the post measurement state is

$$ \sum_{z,x\in \{0,1\}}|zx\rangle\langle zx|\langle zx|\psi|zx\rangle$$

This should be a valid $\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z$ measurement, as $|xz\rangle$ is an eigenbasis of the observable, but this state clearly can't be $\psi$ as it's diagonal in the computational basis. On the other hand the set of Bell states also is an eigenbasis for $\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z$, and writing down the post measurement state  in this basis obviously yields $\psi$, since it's one of the basis elements.

What is going on? It seems to me that measuring the same observable can be made to produce two different outcomes depending on what eigenbasis you choose for it! This obviously doesn't make sense. What am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Isn't your post measurement state diagonal _by construction_?

Comment: Let $\psi = 2e_x + 2 e_y = [2,2]$. Are you saying that $\sum_{i=1,2} c_i e_i$ clearly can't be $\psi$ because it's diagonal in the $e_i$ basis...?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I'm not use I understand your notation. What I'm saying is that the post measurement state I wrote down cannot be $\psi$, because $\psi$ has off diagonal terms like $|01\rangle\langle 10|$, while what I wrote down doesn't, it only has diagonal terms

Comment: Ok, I get that, but as I wrote, is it not diagonal by construction? Did you ever use a property of $\psi$ when writing down this post measurement state?

Comment: Yes, it is diagonal by construction, what I don't understand is why a measurement of $\sigma_z$ by A followed by one by B doesn't leave the state invariant, while a measurement of $\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z$ does

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but when A measures $\sigma_z$ on her subsystem, she is acting on the entangled state $\psi$ with the operator $\sigma_z \otimes \mathbb{1}$, right? When B does the same, the operator is $\mathbb{1} \otimes \sigma_z$. The product of these operators is not equal to $\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z$.

Comment: But back to the measurement state; I still don't understand the form you have written down, because on the one hand you claim that $| zx \rangle$ is a **basis** (in particular an eigenbasis for $\sigma_z \otimes \sigma_z$) but on the other hand you are saying that when the state $\psi$ is projected onto this basis, it cannot give back $\psi$ because the expression only has diagonal terms. But if it is a basis you should be able to express **any** state.

Comment: In particular, if $| zx \rangle$ form one basis and the Bell states form another, then you should be able to do a simple change of basis to get from one to the other.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer the product of those operators does equal $\sigma_z\otimes \sigma_z$, and measuring does not equal acting on the state with the operator, it means projecting the state onto an eigenstate of the operator. As a quantum channel, projecting onto each eigenstate and summing the result multiplied by the corresponding probabilities, which creates a classical probability distribution. This is what I'm meaning here.

Comment: "But if it is a basis you should be able to express any state." I agree, but that particular linear combination of basis states does not correspond to $\psi$, and if I changed basis to the Bell basis, I still would get something other than $\psi$, because I know the form of $\psi$ in the $|xz\rangle$ basis and it contains off diagonal terms.